# Concatenação de função javascript no onclick dentro de php

Tags: php, javascript, concatenação-de-string

Me ajudem por gentileza

```
<?php
          if($dados_login['acesso'] >= 3){
            echo("<div class='col-md-2'>
                         <button type='button' onclick='window.open('icg_historico_excluidos.php?id=".$id."&perfil=1&nome_aps=".$dados_APS['nome_aps']."', '', 'height=690, width=1050, top=90, left=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no');'' class='btn btn-block btn-warning'>Histórico da Exclusão de ICG </button>
                    </div>");
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Olá Jennifer, para que as pessoas possam te ajudar e entender melhor o seu problema recomendo você copiar uma parte maior do código com os pontos críticos e usar a marcação de código no editor de perguntas. Recomendo esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Como regra geral, quando inserir elementos HTML por meio do PHP, você deve sempre:

**1** - Usar aspas duplas escapadas para os atributos dos elementos. Para escapar as aspas, basta colocar a barra invertida antes dela que vai ser interpretada como caractere da string e não delimitar de string. Exemplo:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class=\"minha_classe\"></div>";

    // Resulta no HTML <div class="minha_classe"></div>
?>
```

**2** - Caso precise usar aspas simples para alguma string interna do atributo - como no caso de uma string JavaScript de uma função em algum atributo on (onclick, onblur...) - não haverá conflito se seguiu o que se encontra em 1. Exemplo:

```
<?php
    // Forma sem conflito:
    echo "<div onclick=\"alert('teste');\"></div>";

    // Resulta no HTML <div onclick="alert('teste');"></div>
?>


<?php
    // Forma com conflito:
    echo "<div onclick='alert('teste');'></div>";

    // Resulta no HTML <div onclick='alert('teste');'></div>
?>
```

**Seguindo estas regras**, você consegue facilmente concatenar strings em PHP para aproveitar os valores das variáveis sem erros. Não haverá conflito algum *se fizer corretamente*.

### Seu código

Dei um "tapa" no seu código para melhor compreender o que foi feito. Deste modo, é mais fácil de evitar acometimento de erros. Consequentemente, removeu qualquer erro possível.

Você pode trocar ou reorganizar as variáveis e seus nomes da maneira que achar melhor. Não existe uma única forma de organizar. Mas é importante estar organizado!

```
<?php

    if( $dados_login["acesso"] >= 3 ){

        // Construção dos argumentos de window.open(...)
        $uarg = "id=" . $id . "&perfil=1&nome_aps=" . $dados_APS['nome_aps'];
        $url  = "icg_historico_excluidos.php?" . $uarg;

        $name = "";

        $spec = "height=690,width=1050,top=90,left=500,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no";

        // Argumentos completos de window.open(...)
        $fargs = "'" . $url . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $spec . "'";

        // HTML completo
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";

        echo "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"window.open(" . $fargs . ");\" ";
        echo "class=\"btn btn-block btn-warning\">";

        echo "Histórico da Exclusão de ICG";

        echo "</button>";

        echo "</div>";

    }

?>
```

**Vale notar** que se houver aspas nas variáveis usadas, pode ser que cause algum conflito. Então a recomendação é *prestar muita atenção* e *planejar bem* o modo como vai juntar todas as aspas, *considerando todas as fontes de texto* e seu possível conteúdo! ]

Ou seja: certifique-se do conteúdo de `$dados_APS['nome_aps']` pois pode causar conflito. E *happy hacking*!

Answer (score 0):

Olá jennifer não sei se meu código vai rodar, no entando acho que assim abro seu escopo de possíveis formas de resolver este tipo de complicações com strings no PHP;

```
<?php
if($dados_login['acesso'] >= 3):?>
    <div class='col-md-2'>
        <button type='button' onclick='window.open("icg_historico_excluidos.php?id=<?= $id ?>&perfil=1&nome_aps=<?=$dados_APS['nome_aps']?>,height=690, width=1050, top=90, left=500, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no");' class='btn btn-block btn-warning'>Histórico da Exclusão de ICG </button>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```